# What is the best approach to update a set of documents considering the mongo db performance

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb. I need some input on following scenario.

I have a document  `{ "field1" : "abc", "field2": "xyz", "testId" : "test123" }`

On every transaction, say we receive 1000 such documents and out of these there may be some new documents, say 100 (means there is no entry for these 100 documents).

Now I have 2 approaches to update these documents.
Approach 1: Query for each document to find if it has a db entry else add it to db. (we can use *upsert* method to do this).

Approach 2: Remove all documents which matches particular field value and insert all 1000 documents as new entries using SaveAll.

Can some suggest the best approach on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique index, do a bulk insert and ignore any errors:

```
db.foo.createIndex({ "testId": 1 }, { unique: true })
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/.

```
db.runCommand({
  insert: "foo",
  documents: [
    { "field1" : "abc", "field2": "xyz", "testId" : "test123" },
    ...
  ],
  ordered: false  // continue despite errors
})
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/insert/.